# Else statement in JavaScript not calculating properly

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript and designing a very simple program to
calculate the fine for returning books late to the library.

*If 5 or less days late = 40p per day If 6 - 10 days late = 65p per day If over 10 days late = 80p*

The else statement is returning the wrong amount? In the example
`totalThree` should equal £8.80 for 11 days but result says £7.15?

```
const daysLate = 11;
const totalOne = daysLate * 0.40;
const totalTwo = daysLate * 0.65;
const totalThree = daysLate * 0.80;

if (daysLate <= 5) {
    console.log(`Your fine is £${totalOne}`)
} else if (daysLate >= 6 || daysLate <= 10) {
    console.log(`Your fine is £${totalTwo}`)
} else {
    console.log(`Your fine is £${totalThree}`)
}
```

Comment: Change the OR operator (`||`) to AND (`&&`). Your code is not what you are expecting because the second case, `daysLate >= 6` is true for 11. `true || false` equals `true`.

Comment: You need an AND (`&&`) not an OR (`||`) if you want to catch delays between 6 and 10 days

Answer (score 1):

`(daysLate >= 6 || daysLate <= 10)` is returning `true` becaues 11 >= 6. You need to change the `||` (or) operator into `&&` (and) as shown below. This will check if both conditions are met.

```
else if (daysLate >= 6 && daysLate <= 10) {
    console.log(`Your fine is £${totalTwo}`);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you everyone! Of course, makes perfect sense now :)